# How insert obj to an array Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    category: 'Home',
    body: 'sometext',
    comments: [{
        nickName: 'Meron', 
        comment: 'Hello',  
        date: 'Feb 2 2017, 23:32', 
            commentUnders: [{
                nickName: 'Storseses', 
                comment: 'It's our dat', 
                date: 'Feb 5 2017, 22:03'
            }]
        }]
});
```

How can I `findByIdAndUpdate` commentUnders? I already have in comments one comment which has id "5897518c0a913a842cc041cf". I tried this solve but doesnt work:

```
   Post.findByIdAndUpdate( {'comments._id': '5897518c0a913a842cc041cf'},
        {
            $push: {
                   commentUnders: {
                       "comment" : "Так, что мне делать-то?",
                       "nickName" : "Great",
                       "date" : Date.now()
                   }
              } 
        }, function(err, data) { 
              if (err) {console.log(err); } 
              console.log(data); 
        });
```

Comment: have you defined the Schema like that? or that is how your document looks like?

Comment: `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5896f719c89d211c25ab2787"),
    category: 'Home',
    "comments" : [{
            comment: 'Hello',  
            nickName: 'Meron', 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5897518c0a913a842cc041cf"),
            "commentUnders" : [],
            "date" : ISODate("2017-02-05T16:23:40.018Z")
        }],
    body: 'sometext',
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-05T09:57:45.877Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}` It looks like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$` positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) with **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** function instead of **[`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)** to update the matching `comments` array:

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "comments._id": "5897518c0a913a842cc041cf" },
    {
        "$push": {
            "comments.$.commentUnders": {
                "comment" : "Так, что мне делать-то?",
                "nickName" : "Great",
                "date" : Date.now(),
            }
        }
    }, 
    function(err, data) { 
        if (err) console.log(err); 
        console.log(data); 
    }
);
```